# Write and read binary files in Android

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I created a custom object of type `Task` and I want to save it in a binary file in internal storage. Here is the class I created:

```java
public class Task {

    private String title;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    public Task(String inputTitle, int inputYear, int inputMonth, int inputDay, int inputHour, int inputMinute) {

        this.title = inputTitle;
        this.year = inputYear;
        this.month = inputMonth;
        this.day = inputDay;
        this.hour = inputHour;
        this.minute = inputMinute;

    }

    public String getTitle() {

        return this.title;

    }

    public int getYear() {

        return this.year;

    }

    public int getMonth() {

        return this.month;

    }

    public int getDay() {

        return this.day;

    }

    public int getHour() {

        return this.hour;

    }

    public int getMinute() {

        return this.minute;

    }
}
```

In an activity, I created a method that will save my object to a file. This is the code I used:

```java
public void writeData(Task newTask) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("data", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        fOut.write(newTask.getTitle().getBytes());
        fOut.write(newTask.getYear());
        fOut.write(newTask.getMonth());
        fOut.write(newTask.getDay());
        fOut.write(newTask.getHour());
        fOut.write(newTask.getMinute());
        fOut.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I would like to create a method that will extract the data from the file. By reading on the internet, a lot of people use `FileInputStream` but I have trouble with extracting the bytes from it and knowing how long a String can be. Furthermore, I used a simple method found online but I get permission denied. As I said, I am very new to Android development.

```java
public void readData(){
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("data");
        System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                + fis.available());
        int content;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            // convert to char and display it
            System.out.print((char) content);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null)
                fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For permission issues, I encourage you to use an external storage such as an SD card.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

you can create a folder there and save your files. You can also use "/data/local/" if your system permits user files to be saved there.
You can refer to this [page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) regarding the various ways you can save files to internal and external storage,

For the second problem I suggest you to use [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html),

```
File file = new File("myFile");
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
dis.readFully(fileData);
dis.close();
```

You can code something like this,

```
import java.io.*;
public class Sequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    String str="Enter your Age :";
    System.out.print(str);
    int i=dis.readInt();
    System.out.println((int)i);
    }
}
```

You can also Use [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface for reading and writing serializable objects. In fact, I used this once when I tried to write data values directly to files instead of any traditional databases (In my very first undergraduate years, I was not familiar with databases). A good example is [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57),

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

/** JDK before version 7. */
public class ExerciseSerializable {

  public static void main(String... aArguments) {
    //create a Serializable List
    List<String> quarks = Arrays.asList(
      "up", "down", "strange", "charm", "top", "bottom"
    );

    //serialize the List
    //note the use of abstract base class references

    try{
      //use buffering
      OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("quarks.ser");
      OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
      ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
      try{
        output.writeObject(quarks);
      }
      finally{
        output.close();
      }
    }  
    catch(IOException ex){
      fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform output.", ex);
    }

    //deserialize the quarks.ser file
    //note the use of abstract base class references

    try{
      //use buffering
      InputStream file = new FileInputStream("quarks.ser");
      InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
      ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream (buffer);
      try{
        //deserialize the List
        List<String> recoveredQuarks = (List<String>)input.readObject();
        //display its data
        for(String quark: recoveredQuarks){
          System.out.println("Recovered Quark: " + quark);
        }
      }
      finally{
        input.close();
      }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
      fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform input. Class not found.", ex);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
      fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform input.", ex);
    }
  }

  // PRIVATE 

  //Use Java's logging facilities to record exceptions.
  //The behavior of the logger can be configured through a
  //text file, or programmatically through the logging API.
  private static final Logger fLogger =
    Logger.getLogger(ExerciseSerializable.class.getPackage().getName())
  ;
}
```

Comment: I like the idea using Serializable Interface. But I would prefer to save it in internal storage. Is there a way to bypass the permission denied?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier you can save in /data/local most of the times it is accessible in user mode. If you want a custom directory you have to root the phone and change the permission of the directory. otherwise you have to use the data region assigned to the app.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

and also, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are trying to dump the contents of the object into a file and then read it back. But the way you are doing it now is just writing all the data to the file without any structure, which is a terrible idea.

I would recommend you try to implement the [Serializable interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) and then just use the writeObject() and readObject() methods.

Alternatively, you could dump the data into an XML file or something that has some structure to it.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides a private directory structure to each application for exactly this kind of data.  You don't need special permissions to access it.  The only caveat (which is generally a good caveat) is that *only* your app can access it.  (This principle is part of the security that prevents other apps from doing bad things to you.)

If this meets you need for storage, just call `getFilesDir()` from whatever context is readily available (usually your activity).  It looks like in your case you would want to pass the context as a parameter of `readData()` and `writeData()`.  Or you could call `getFilesDir()` to get the storage directory and then pass that as the parameter to `readData()` and `writeData()`.

One other caveat (learned the hard way).  Although undocumented, I've found that sometimes Android will create files in this application directory.  I strongly recommend that rather than storing files directly in this application folder you instead create your own storage directory in the application directory returned by `getFilesDir()`, and then store your files there.  That way you won't have to worry about other files that might show up, for example if you try to list the files in the storage directory.

```
File myStorageFolder = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "myStorageFolder");
```

(I agree with P basak that `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` are your best option for reading and writing the data.  I disrecommend Serialization except in a very narrow set of applications where transportability is a factor as it is very inefficient.  In my case objects that took 15 seconds to load via Serialization loaded in less than 2 seconds using `DataInputStream`.)